# Undefined function error when creating Custom Meta Box

Tags: metabox

Following [this tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes/), I am trying to create a custom Meta Box on my theme by adding following codes to the `function.php` file:

```
add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'My First Meta Box', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );

function cd_meta_box_add()
{
  add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'My First Meta Box', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function cd_meta_box_cb()  
{  
  echo 'What you put here, show\'s up in the meta box';     
}
```

but I am getting following error :

[image: fatal error]

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_meta_box() in C:\wamp\www\TMPress\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\cpt.php on line 94
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0012  865440  {main}( )   ..\edit.php:0
2   0.0018  982824  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\TMPress\wp-admin\admin.php' )    ..\edit.php:10
3   0.0021  1008744 require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\TMPress\wp-load.php' )   ..\admin.php:30
4   0.0023  1026872 require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\TMPress\wp-config.php' ) ..\wp-load.php:29
5   0.0029  1158248 require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\TMPress\wp-settings.php' )   ..\wp-config.php:90
6   0.3251  32951888    include( 'C:\wamp\www\TMPress\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\functions.php' )   ..\wp-settings.php:291
7   0.3255  32979176    include_once( 'C:\wamp\www\TMPress\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\cpt.php' )    ..\functions.php:2
```

Can you please let me know why this is happening? is there any better way to add a meta box containing a field and dropdown select box? I know there are some plugins out there for doing this but I really like to learn it on my own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );

function cd_meta_box_add()
{
  add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'My First Meta Box', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function cd_meta_box_cb()  
{  
  echo 'What you put here, show\'s up in the meta box';     
}
```

ps: you have some extra problematic lines, at the top of your code, that I removed, namely:

```
add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'My First Meta Box', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
```

### Update:

To add the metabox to your custom post type edit page, replace `'post'` with `'your-custom-post-type'` in this line:

```
add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'My First Meta Box', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'your-custom-post-type', 'normal', 'high' );
```

Comment: Hi Bitgire, thanks I am nit getting any error now but there is not any meta box on the page! I mean in Posts admin page!

Comment: check your post edit page.

Comment: sorry man I find it at is added to Post! can you please let me know how to customize it to only added to my Custom post Type?

Comment: ok great, I updated the answer to show you how you can do that.

Comment: Or use the action `add_meta_boxes_your-post-type`.

Comment: I think the `enter code here` line is an editing "error" here in the Stack interface. I noticed recently that if we click `{}` in an empty space, it prints exactly that in the editing box.

Comment: @brasofilo aha I have not encounter that before, but I checked and you are right about that.